# How to download mysql file from digital ocean server Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I have been searching everywhere how to download .sql file from digital ocean server tried executing this command

```
 mysqldump -u root  -p dbfilename  > dbfile.sql
```

i can see in command line ls -a .sql file but its hidden how to download that hidden file

Comment: Do you have FTP access?

Comment: yes i have access to ftp and i can see the file in terminal ls -a but its hidden

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i got it changed settings show hidden files in ftp..
thank you #RiggisFolly for having a look at this question